# Windows 8 PointerEntered for elements which are placed under another elements

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, events, xaml

I have a graphic application. To make interface a have made my own UserControl elements and placed them on top of each other using absolute positioning.

For example I have such structure:

```
<Canvas>
        <local:UserControl1 Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" PointerEntered="onPointerEntered"/>
        <local:UserControl2 Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" PointerEntered="onPointerEntered"/>
</Canvas>
```

UserControl2 has transparent background and UserControl1 is visible through it.
I'm trying to catch PointerEntered event for both: UserControl1 and UserControl2.
But because of UserControl2 being placed over UserControl1, PointerEntered  is fired only for UserControl2 object, but I need to catch this event for both.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show the event handler itself?

Comment: What for? It's not being called. Only for UserControl2

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Not exact what I wanted, but also suites me.
I've changed local:UserControl2 IsHitTestVisible to false for a time.